# How to specify a specific tsconfig.json in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

WebStorm by default takes the `tsconfig.json` in the root directory of a project. Is there any way that we can point this to custom tsconfig.json file path using the settings?

I can see the options in TypeScript section of WebStorm settings, but I cannot figure out the correct way to specify tsconfig.json.

Comment: It looks like there isn't an option to specify which tsconfig is used - ideally all of them. It just uses the `tsconfig` by default`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `-p` option of the [`tsc` command](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#tsc--b-commandline).

On webstorm, click on configure (the wrench)

[image]

Then add `-p yourTsConfig.json` in the `Options` field.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If **Recompile on changes** is enabled in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, it uses the nearest `tsconfig.json` current file is included in, scanning folders from the file folder up to the project root.
If it's disabled, you can compile using **Compile** button in **Typescript** tool window toolbar - when pressing this button, you can choose a `tsconfig.json` to be used for compilation

[image]